# Flush and send response object periodically in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I am new to Node.js and i am trying to refresh the data periodically using the below code:

```
router.post('/getMessage',function(req,res){
    setInterval(findMessage,5000);
    function findMessage() {
        Message.find(
            {
                $or: [
                    {sender: req.body.sender, receiver: req.body.receiver},
                    {sender: req.body.receiver, receiver: req.body.sender}
                ]
            },
            (err, data) => {
                res.send({success: true, data: data});
            }
        );
    }
    });
```

But this gives an error: "Cannot set headers after they are sent". I understand that res.send calls res.end() implicitly and therefore this error is occuring. And  have tried res.write() also. But i am returning an object and not a String or buffer, hence it also failed to work.

It would be great if someone could give an example of how to achieve this exactly.

Comment: What you are trying to do is generally called Comet (also sometimes known as long polling, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). It is not as simple as what you've attempted because you need to cater for different browsers and different browser versions. It used to be popular before websockets. Read the linked wikipedia articled to understand what it is you are trying to do and how people have attempted to make it work with browsers

Comment: You can also search for the term "comet" on npmjs to find implementations of real-time communications protocols (including websockets). These days I'd recommend that people use websockets for this because comet is basically a hack trying to use things like iframes or script tags or java applets etc to implement a feature that did not exist in browsers. That feature now exist and it's websockets.

Comment: Every response you can only send once. Look at socket.io where you can send multiple messages through a single connection (with websockets natively or emulated with polling)

Comment: REST works based on request and response. Each request can only have one response. What you're looking for should be implemented via sockets. Take a look at `socket.io` examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response.send() method does two task

```
1. write content on the response and send.
2. End connection with res.end().
```

So, when you did response.send(), then it sends your message and closes the connection. For that reason, you getting the error "Cannot set headers after they are sent".

So, the conclusion is that you can't send multiple responses using response.send().

You can achieve this by the socket.io or you can make the request from frontend after an interval.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `res.write()`, but you also need to send the head before (status code + headers)